# Loading partial view with an Edit Form doesn't overload correctly

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to load an edit form which is a PartialView, into a div using jQuery. I am overloading the EditUser action. The 1st one is for passing the id and loading the form with existing details. The 2nd one is for posting back the form for save. But it seems to call the 2nd method when I load using jQuery and Url.Action. If I comment out the 2nd EditUser method, then it calls the 1st method. Why is that? How can I make it call the 1st one when I pass staffID? Or is there a better way to implement this Edit form in partial view scenario??

And the CreateUser action works just fine as there is no ambiguity on the overloaded methods as 1 has no parameters and the other has a model as parameter.

Thanks

This is my controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult EditUser(String staffId)
    {
        User um = userService.GetUserDetails(1, staffId, true);
        return PartialView(um);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult EditUser(User um)
    {
        if (!TryUpdateModel(um))
        {
            ViewBag.updateError = "Edit Failure";
            return PartialView("EditUser", um);
        }

        userService.CreateUpdateUser(um);
        return PartialView("ViewUser", um);
    }

    public PartialViewResult CreateUser()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Create New User";
        return PartialView(new User());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(User um)
    {

        if (!TryUpdateModel(um))
        {
            ViewBag.updateError = "Create Failure";
            return PartialView(um);
        }

        userService.CreateUpdateUser(um);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

This is how I am loading my EditUser partialview:

```
function menuEdit() {
    $('#ActionMenu').hide();
    $('#SearchBar').hide();
    $('#SearchPanel').hide();
    $('#SearchResult').hide();
    $('#AddViewEditUser').load("@Url.Action("EditUser","User")", {staffId : sId});
    $('#AddViewEditUser').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed."  Since you are providing data, `.load()` is using the method "POST", thus your second `EditUser()` is being called.

Comment: Thanks for Replying! I changed my code to following... 
        $('#AddViewEditUser').load("@Url.Action("EditUser","User", new { staffId = "sId" } )");
        So now it is calling the 1st method. I have to figure out how to access the local variable though istead of hardcoding "sId".